# Clicking on link tag navigates to new page without sidebar

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm new to ReactJS and I am trying to create a frontend similar to https://react.dev/learn/installation where users can click on the tabs on the sidebar and render the new page on the side. The URL will also change depending on the tab that was clicked on the sidebar and the sidebar will persist on the side.

The issue is that when I click on the tabs, it navigates me to the correct page but the sidebar is missing.

**Routes in App.js**

```
function App() {
   

    return (
        <>
            <div>
                <center>
                    <span>
                        <NavBar></NavBar>
                    </span>
                </center>
            </div>
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/" element={<HomePage></HomePage>}></Route>
                <Route path="/development">
                    <Route
                        index
                        element={<DevelopmentPage></DevelopmentPage>}
                    ></Route>
                    <Route path=":id" element={<ChildPage></ChildPage>}></Route>
                </Route>
                <Route path="/about" element={<AboutPage></AboutPage>}></Route>
                <Route
                    path="/contact"
                    element={<ContactPage></ContactPage>}
                ></Route>
            </Routes>
        </>
    )
}

export default App
```

This is the code for my sidebar

```
export default function SideBar({
    sideBarParentTabsState,
    onSetsideBarParentTabsState
}) {
    const [isShowChildrenComponents, setIsShowChildrenComponents] =
        useState(false)
    const sideBarContextArr = useContext(SideBarContext)

    function SideBarParentTab({parentTabProps}) {
        return (
            <button
                className="sidebar"
                onClick={() => {
                    setIsShowChildrenComponents(!isShowChildrenComponents)
                }}
            >
                {parentTabProps.name}
            </button>
        )
    }

    function SideBarChildTab({childTabProps}) {
        return (
            <>
                <div>
                    <Link to={`${childTabProps.id}`}>  // When I click the child tab in the side bar, this links me to the page.
                        <button
                            onClick={() =>
                                console.log('child component clicked')
                            }
                        >
                            {childTabProps.name}
                        </button>
                    </Link>
                </div>
            </>
        )
    }

functions
    function isParentTabStateActive(index) {
        return sideBarParentTabsState[index]
    }

    function handleParentTabState(index) {
        const sideBarParentTabsStateCopy = sideBarParentTabsState.slice()
        sideBarParentTabsStateCopy[index] = !sideBarParentTabsStateCopy[index]
        onSetsideBarParentTabsState(sideBarParentTabsStateCopy)
    }

    function renderSideBarChildTabs(parentTab) {
        return parentTab.childTabs.map((childTabProps) => {
            return (
                <>
                    {
                        <SideBarChildTab
                            childTabProps={childTabProps}
                        ></SideBarChildTab>
                    }
                </>
            )
        })
    }

    return (
        <>
            <span>
                {sideBarTabsTestData.map((parentTabs, index) => {
                    return (
                        <>
                            {
                                <div
                                    onClick={() => handleParentTabState(index)}
                                >
                                    <SideBarParentTab
                                        parentTabProps={parentTabs}
                                    ></SideBarParentTab>
                                    {isParentTabStateActive(index)
                                        ? renderSideBarChildTabs(parentTabs)
                                        : null}
                                </div>
                            }
                        </>
                    )
                })}
            </span>
            <Outlet></Outlet>
        </>
    )
}
```

This is my child page.

```
export default function ChildPage() {
    const {id} = useParams()

    return (
        <div>
            <center>
                <h1>CHILD Page {id} </h1>{' '}
            </center>
        </div>
    )
}
```

[image: Development page with the sidebar]

[image: After clicking the childtab on the sidebar]

One of the solutions I can think of is to put the sidebar as an element in the parent route

```
<Route path="/development" element= {<SideBar/>} >
     <Route index
        element={<DevelopmentPage></DevelopmentPage>}
         ></Route>
         <Route path=":id" element={<ChildPage></ChildPage>}></Route>
</Route>
```

but this would mean that the state of the sidebar will have to be in App.js and I'll essentially pass down the props from App -> DevelopmentPage -> Sidebar & Child which I want to avoid because I don't want to be prop drilling.

How can I have the state of the Sidebar stored in the DevelopmentPage as well as the child and the sidebar existing as components within the developmentPage and child page change depending on the tab that was clicked in the sidebar?

**TLDR:**
How can I get the sidebar to persist in all navigated components within the development page.

P.S Sorry for the long post, do let me know if you need me to provide or remove unnecessary code or information.

Comment: I have updated the post above with pictures of the page.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried putting your  component near the same section as your  component and then adjusting the positioning/alignment html/css?

Something along the lines of:

```
 <div>
   <center>
     <span>
       <NavBar></NavBar>
    </span>
  </center>
</div>
<div>
   <SideBar />
   <Routes>
    ...
   </Routes>
</div>
```

Also - it'll make it easier to help out if you come up with a codepen (or equivalent) exhibiting the issue.